# How to automate setting position and dimensions to round values?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, illustrator-scripting

I'm trying to set the position and size of selected objects in Illustrator to whole numbers quickly.

Is there an Action or Script that does that already?

If so, where can I find that?

Otherwise, what would be the fastest workflow?

(So far I'm tabbing through the Transform Panel and manually rounding and iterating through elements, which is slow)

Comment: From how I interprate you question. You could create a Action using the Effect->Transform to use a general scale and move. Going about it this way would allow you to set a global change to objects in a document/artboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid decimals on position and size using pixels](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18809/how-to-avoid-decimals-on-position-and-size-using-pixels)

Comment: @Luciano that question assumes working in pixels. If you're working in any unit other than pixels/points then that won't work.

Comment: @Cai True. I assumed pixels would be the most troublesome unit, since  blurred lines can occur when not aligned to the pixel grid.

Comment: True pixels are the most probable case, question doesn't specify though. And that question is only relevant for new objects, not adjusting existing objects.

Comment: [This](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64365/script-to-automatically-snap-all-points-to-grid-in-adobe-illustrator) on the other hand does exactly what OP wants (or wanted)...

Comment: Actually, no it doesn't... that is about points, not position/size. Long day.

Answer (score 1):

Next time you could set up a grid and let the artboard and all objects snap to it.

> - To use the grid, choose *View > Show Grid.*
> - To hide the grid, choose *View > Hide Grid.*
> - To snap objects to gridlines, choose *View > Snap To Grid,*
>     (Note: When the *View > Pixel Preview* option is selected, Snap To Grid
>     changes to *Snap To Pixel.*)
> - To specify the spacing between gridlines, choose *Edit > Preferences >
>     Guides & Grid (Windows)* or *Illustrator > Preferences > Guides & Grid
>     (Mac OS).*
>
> Source: http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rulers-grids-guides-crop-marks.html#use_the_grid