# Script to automatically snap all points to grid in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: cs6, grids, illustrator-scripting, javascript

How would you write a script to move all points of all selected paths to the nearest (non-pixel grid) grid point?

[image: Sample before and after alignment]

*e.g. I want all of the points of each polygon/path to snap to the nearest point on a custom grid. Mine is setup as 1 grid unit = 11.338px or 4mm, but ideally the script would extend to any unit value*

**MY PSEUDOCODE, v0.1:**

```
// set grid units as pixels - in my case 11.338px = 8mm = 1 grid unit

units = 11.338 


// Nested loop through all polygons/paths, then all points in each polygon

For each Polygon {

    For each Point P in Polygon {

    // move the Point x, y to the nearest grid point in units
        P.x = units * Round(P.x/units) 
        P.y = units * Round(P.y/units)
    }
}
```

Does this make sense? It's been a while since I've done any programming.
I've also never scripted for Illustrator, so not exactly sure how to implement this.

**LINK:** I've looked at the post by @KromStern but not sure how to implement based on that thread. [How to align all selected points to a grid?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25365/how-to-align-all-selected-points-to-a-grid)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go, make sure the paths that you want to snap are selected:

```
  // jooSnapToDocumentGrid.jsx

#target illustrator

main();

function main(){
    var grid = getDocumentGrid();
    snapSelectedPathToDocumentGrid(activeDocument.selection, grid); 
}

function snapSelectedPathToDocumentGrid(sel, grid){
    for(var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++){
        try {
            var pp = sel[i].pathPoints;
            for(var j = 0; j < pp.length; j++){
                var p = pp[j];
                p.leftDirection = nearestGrid(p.leftDirection, grid);
                p.rightDirection = nearestGrid(p.rightDirection, grid);
                p.anchor = nearestGrid(p.anchor, grid);       
            }
        } catch(err) { }
    }
}

function getDocumentGrid(){
    var prf = app.preferences;
    var ticks = prf.getIntegerPreference('Grid/Horizontal/Ticks');
    var spacing = prf.getRealPreference('Grid/Horizontal/Spacing');
    return spacing/ticks;    
}

function nearestGrid(anchor, grid) {
    return [Math.round(anchor[0] / grid) * grid, 
            Math.round(anchor[1] / grid) * grid ];
}
```

Comment: **This is great, @joojaa!** Thank you for the code! I've tested your script on a few polygons as a selection and _it works flawlessly_, aligning points to the grid. Unfortunately, when I select my hundreds of polygons, I'm getting an error message **(Error:21: undefined is not an object, Line 15) >> _I'm guessing there must be a problem with my selection_** (e.g. an unclosed path or some non path object that I am not seeing on my artboard that is not a valid object for your script. Will have to take a closer look. Thanks again, you rock!

Comment: @Johnnystackexchange Yeah well i dont check for object types you should add check to see if the selected object is a path Item or wrap a try catch block around the loop.

Comment: @Johnnystackexchange try now didn't do any testing on it